Converting $\frac{1}{s^3+a_2s^2+a_1s+a_0}$ to a product of second and first order terms
I am dealing with a transfer function of the form
$$H(s) = \frac{1}{s^3+a_2s^2+a_1s+a_0}$$
where the coefficients are real but unknown. Is it always possible to convert the transfer function to a product of a second and first order term, like this:
$$H(s) = \frac{1}{s+a_{10}} \cdot \frac{1}{s^2 + a_{21}s+a_{20}} $$
If so, I would be very interested to see how this is done, i.e. what is the relation between the original $a_2, a_1, a_0$ coefficients and the new $a_{10}, a_{21}, a_{20}$ coefficients.

Every cubic can be factored in such a way - doing this in general, however, is quite difficult.

@SeanRoberson Is it scaleable? Can you also factor quadruple and quintic polynomials with undetermined coefficients like this?

The fundamental theorem of algebra (or rather, a corollary thereof) says that every polynomial can be factored into a product of linear factors. If you only permit real factors, then you can do this with a bunch of linear and irreducible quadratics. Again, this is generally hard.

For a cubic $y=f(x)$ with real coefficients, at $x$ values of large enough magnitude the cubic term dominates, so $y$ always goes from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ or vice versa. The cubic $y=f(x)$ is continuous, so has to pass through $y=0$ at least once along the way.  We conclude a cubic with real coefficients has at least one real zero.
How do we factor the monic $s^3+a_2s^2+a_1s + a_0$?  We need to write down the real root. Let's try to get at it with some substitutions that avoid fractions down the line:
Solve $s^3 + 3 B s^2 + 6 C s + 2D = 0 \ $ where $\ B= \dfrac {a_2} {3}, \ C = \dfrac {a_1} {6} , \ D = \dfrac {a_0}{2}$
Let $s=y-B$
$$(y-B)^3 + 3 B (y-B)^2 + 6 C(y-B) x + 2D = 0$$
$$(y^3 - 3By^2 +3B^2y -B^3)+ (3By^2 - 6B^2y +3B^3)  + 6Cy  - 6CB+2D=0$$
The $y^2$ term vanishes and we’re left with a depressed cubic.
$$y^3 + (6C - 3B^2)y  = 6BC -2B^3 - 2D$$
$$y^3 + 3py = 2q   \ \ \textrm{ where }
 \ \   p = 2C-B^2, \ q=3BC-B^2-D $$
We split our unknown $y$ into two unknowns $t$ and $u$.
Let $y=t+u$.
$$2q = y^3 + 3py = (t+u)^3+3p(t+u)=  y^3 + 3tu(t+u)+u^3+3p(t+u)$$
$$2q = (t^3+u^3) + 3(tu+p)(t+u)$$
If we could solve simultaneous equations $t^3+u^3=2q$ and $tu+p=0$ we’d have a solution to our depressed cubic. Fortunately that’s not too hard,
$$u=-p/t$$
$$t^3+(-p/t)^3 = 2q$$
$$(t^3)^2 - 2q \; t^3 - p^3  = 0$$
That’s a quadratic in $t^3,$ so
$$t^3 = q \pm \sqrt{p^3 + q^2}$$
By the symmetry of our formulation ($t$ and $u$ are interchangable) when one of these is $t^3$, the other is $u^3$. We don’t really care which is which; we’re after $y=t+u$, so
$$y = \sqrt[3]{q+\sqrt{p^3+q^2}} +  \sqrt[3]{q-\sqrt{p^3+q^2}} $$
That’s the solution to the depressed cubic $y^3 + 3py = 2q.$ It’s ambiguous this way because each cube root has three values (at least two complex) for nine possible sums, more than the 3 roots we expect, as we've lost the constraint  $tu=-p$. It's something to remember, but I won't mention it further.
Unwinding,
$$\ B= \dfrac {a_2} {3}, \ C = \dfrac {a_1} {6} , \ D = \dfrac {a_0}{2}$$
$$ p = 2C-B^2 = \dfrac{3  a_1 - a_2^2}{9 }
, \ \ q = 3BC-B^2-D = \dfrac{ 3 a_1 a_2  -9 a_0 - 2 a_2^2 }{18 } $$
$$s = - B + y, \quad y = \sqrt[3]{q+\sqrt{p^3+q^2}} + \sqrt[3]{q-\sqrt{p^3+q^2}} $$
$$s = -\dfrac {a_2} {3} +  \sqrt[3]{ \dfrac{ 3 {a_2} c -9  d - 2 {a_2}^2 }{18 } +\sqrt{ \left( \dfrac{3  c - {a_2}^2}{9 } \right) ^3+ \left( \dfrac{ 3 {a_2} c -9 d - 2 b^2 }{18  } \right)^2}}  \\ \quad +  \sqrt[3]{ \dfrac{ 3 b c -9 d - 2 {a_2}^2 }{18 } -\sqrt{ \left( \dfrac{3 c - {a_2}^2}{9 } \right) ^3+ \left( \dfrac{ 3 {a_2} c -9 d - 2 {a_2}^2 }{18 } \right)^2}}$$
I’m not going to try to simplify that.  To conform to the form of our problem, we get
$$a_{10}=-s_1$$
where $s_1$ is a real root.
Which is the real root?  It depends if the common radicand of both square roots is negative or not.  In the non-negative case, the square roots yield a real, and both cube roots are of real numbers. That's the single real root case. If the common radicand is negative, the square roots are imaginary, and then we're taking cube roots of complex conjugates. In that case we need to choose cube roots that are themselves complex conjugates to get a real zero; each of the three complex cube roots yields a real root.
I'm not sure how to write the quadratic term in general; perhaps multiplying out $(x-s_2)(x-s_3)$ for two of the roots $s_2$, $s_3$ (choosing complex conjugates if available).

Let $s_1,s_2,s_3$ are the roots of the polynomial $s^3+a_2s^2+a_1s+a_0$. Then $$H(s) = \frac{1}{s-s_1} \cdot \frac{1}{s^2 -(s_2+s_3)s+s_2 s_3}$$
